# Sequential Criterion of Continuity vs Uniformly continuous functions and Cauchy sequences

Tags: real-analysis

We know that a function $f$ is continous iff for every convergent sequence $\{S_n\}$, $f(S_n)$ is convergent.

Likewise, I just encountered a theorem that states $f$ is uniformly continuous if for every Cauchy sequence $\{S_n\}$, $f(S_n)$ is Cauchy. (I believe the converse is true?)

But what I don't understand is that uniform continuity is stronger than continuity, but being Cauchy is weaker than being convergent. Thus, why can't we write the theorem on uniformly continuous functions in terms of convergent sequences. In other words, if $uniform$ $continuity \Rightarrow continuity$ then why don't we have $uniform$ $contininuity$ $\Leftarrow\Rightarrow$ it maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any continuous function maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences and continuous functions need not be uniformly continuous. So your equivalence does not hold. (I think the mistake you are making is to think only in one direction and then make an iff statement).

Comment: I guess what I am asking is if we have that every continuous function maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences, then we have that every uniformly continuous function does the same, and since saying something is convergent is stronger than saying something is Cauchy, wouldn't we want to write a theorem in terms of convergence and not if it is Cauchy or not? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user612713 Every uniformly continuous function surely maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences but the converse is not true. If you want an if and only if statement you cannot stick to convergent sequences. That is why you switch to Cauchy sequences.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you!